# json string to java object to populate spinner

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

So i have a Json string that i have retrieved from my PHP script on my MySQL server

```
{"Clientid":[24,26,27],"companyname":["chelsea","Microsoft","IBM"]}
```

and i have been trying to push this into a java objects in-order to populate a spinner at the moment the spinner on each line shows "chelsea","Microsoft","IBM" but i would like to show each company on a separate line so the user can select which company

current code

```
String response = stringBuilder.toString();
Log.d("response", response);
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
Log.d("response", jsonResponse.toString());
responseStreamReader.close();
Log.d("length", Integer.toString(jsonResponse.length()));
if (jsonResponse.length() == 0) {
returnedClient = null;
} else {
List<Client> myClients;
myClients = new ArrayList<Client>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
Client client = new Client();
client.clientid = jsonResponse.getString("Clientid");
client.companyname = jsonResponse.getString("companyname");
myClients.add(client);
}
returnedClient = myClients;
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
//Log.d("returnedUser", returnedUser.userpassword);
return returnedClient;
```

current code is obviously the wrong code so i have been looking at Gson and Jackson and volley and getting in a mess so i have been looking at the below but cant get it right to fit the Json string so wondered if you could help please or advise a better solution?

```
JSONArray jarray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("companyname");
ArrayList<String> xyz= new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
JSONArray timeArray =jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("companyname");
for(int j = 0; j < timeArray .length(); j++){
xyz.add(timeArray .getString(j));
Log.d("get value",timeArray .getString(j));
```

Is there something im missing with the parser as doesnt matter what i change it seems to not like anything i do, it says the json cant be an object then it cant be an array, i assume the json is an object then an array but at the mormnt i just get errors :(

```
try {
List<Client> returnedClient = null;
// JSONObject json = new JSONObject(content);
JSONArray json1 = new JSONArray(content);
//JSONObject dataObject1 = json.getJSONObject("Clientid");
//JSONObject dataObject2 = json.getJSONObject("companyname");
//   JSONArray items1 = json.getJSONArray("Clientid");
// JSONObject items2 = json.getJSONObject("companyname");
// JSONArray items1 = json.getJSONArray("Clientid");
JSONArray items2 = json1.getJSONArray(0);
for (int i = 0; i < items2.length(); i++) {
//   JSONArray clientObject1 = items1.getJSONArray(i);
//  JSONObject clientObject2 = items2.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray clientObject3 = items2.getJSONArray(i);
//  Client client = new Client(clientObject2);
Log.d("response",clientObject3.toString());
// returnedClient.add(client);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating Spinner with JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603733/populating-spinner-with-json)

Comment: JSONArray timeArray     =jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("companyname");
this line should be change to 
    String companyValue= jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString();

Comment: thanks for the quick response but i get an error that the getJSONObject(i) jsonobject cant ref a int :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O silly me the is was further up the tree as i  was using the code below at the top of the page before i even started the parse, shame it took me to re write my sql before i noticed :(

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```